# How do I get my DC bot to append a txt file, that's on github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, bots, discord.js

I have a really simple Discord bot, that sends a random line of a text file to the chat. The bot itself is on GitHub and is deployed by Heroku. There's a feature that appends the txt file with a new line of text, but it doesn't seem to be working when the bot is running from my Github repo and not my computer. Is there a way that the bot could write into the text file? Or maybe a workaround?
(The bot and the text file are both in the same repo and directory.)
Thanks!

```
else if (msg.content.startsWith('!new')){
    const args = msg.content.slice(5);
    fs.appendFile("text.txt", '\n'+args, () => {});
    msg.channel.send('New line added. Noice.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk, but those files will not persist after the application is restarted. This means that the only way to save to a file is either by using an external cloud storage such as Amazon’s S3, or you could just switch to a different host with a permanent hard drive (I personally recommend [Glitch](https://glitch.com) - It's free).

[Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku)